# Caching in EclipseLink - Prevent repeated queries with same parameters

Tags: java, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa, eclipselink

I am trying to create a project with EclipseLink JPA and SpringBoot, and I've configured two entities as below:

```
class A{
     @OneToOne
     @JoinColumn(name = "UPDTR_ID", referencedColumnName = "PRSN_ID")
     private Person updater;

     @OneToOne
     @JoinColumn(name = "CREATR_ID", referencedColumnName = "PRSN_ID")
     private Person creator;

     @OneToOne
     @JoinColumn(name = "ASGNE_ID", referencedColumnName = "PRSN_ID")
     private Person assignee;

    ...

}

class Person{
    @Id
    @Column(name = "PRSN_ID")
    private String prsnId;

    ...


}
```

When I do a `findAll()` on class `A`, for every entry I see there are 3 queries to the Person table, even when the same id is in all three properties. I assumed that if an ID 1 is fetched from Person, if that id is used in anywhere in the list of `A`s, it would not fire additional queries!

Am I missing a configuration? I've tried `@Cache` and `@Cacheable` with no difference.

I've pasted the config file [here](https://pastebin.com/Y7UgNNDs)  and application.properties contains just 3 elements with spring.datasource.url, username and password.

Comment: paste you actual configuration

Comment: Updated the question with config file location: https://pastebin.com/Y7UgNNDs

Comment: How are you seeing these 3 queries being executed?